# Angularjs str_pad_left

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Is there any angularjs or javascript function similiar to PHP str_pad_left ?

I could not get any result no input was written on screen.

Also i did not now if is it valid to pass the first parameter inside : {{}}.

I try use javascript str_pad function :

```
<script>
      var num = str_pad({{ item.ID }}, 10,'','STR_PAD_LEFT') 
      document.write(num);
      console.log('num '+num);
</script>
```

From this script :

```
    function str_pad(input, pad_length, pad_string, pad_type) {
  var half = '',
    pad_to_go;

  var str_pad_repeater = function(s, len) {
    var collect = '',
      i;

    while (collect.length < len) {
      collect += s;
    }
    collect = collect.substr(0, len);

    return collect;
  };

  input += '';
  pad_string = pad_string !== undefined ? pad_string : ' ';

  if (pad_type !== 'STR_PAD_LEFT' && pad_type !== 'STR_PAD_RIGHT' && pad_type !== 'STR_PAD_BOTH') {
    pad_type = 'STR_PAD_RIGHT';
  }
  if ((pad_to_go = pad_length - input.length) > 0) {
    if (pad_type === 'STR_PAD_LEFT') {
      input = str_pad_repeater(pad_string, pad_to_go) + input;
    } else if (pad_type === 'STR_PAD_RIGHT') {
      input = input + str_pad_repeater(pad_string, pad_to_go);
    } else if (pad_type === 'STR_PAD_BOTH') {
      half = str_pad_repeater(pad_string, Math.ceil(pad_to_go / 2));
      input = half + input + half;
      input = input.substr(0, pad_length);
    }
  }

  return input;
}
```

Comment: using plain javascript i have this working version here : http://embed.plnkr.co/81aFIijn6VEJmCmbkDCc/ how can i move to angularjs ?

Comment: may be make a filter, and use like this -  `{{1234 | pad:'0':true }}` - sample - untested - http://plnkr.co/edit/anwZlsnBjvEkU6shamXv?p=info